# python 2.7.5, getting multiple user input for loading more than 1 array/list, problems with looping

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

I'm doing a programming problem for school in which I need to get 3 student ages/ names, I got the prompt working correctly to load the 2 arrays but for some reason the loop doesn't exit? Here is my code so far. I've been having trouble with arrays/list so please elaborate on your answer and I appreciate the reply. 
Here is the code:

```
#the sample input was: 
#joe 35, bill 25, mary 50 
g = 0 #index for age 
n = 0 #index for name 
while g <= 3 and n <= 3: #1st loop to get 3 names/ ages 
    st_names = [0] * 3
    st_age = [0] * 3
    g = g + 1
    n = n + 1
    for n in range(0,3): #loop used in our book for loading arrays 
        st_names[n] = raw_input("Enter Student name")

        st_age[g] = int(raw_input("Enter student age "))
    g = g + 1 #I'm not sure where to increment
n = n + 1
#the loop goes on forever, my goal was to get the student age/ name one after another,
#for example enter name, then age, 3 times then move on.
```

Comment: `g <= 3` this is not correct. The `while` will do *4* iterations.

Comment: Don't tell me your teacher introduced `input` to you? In python2 `input` is *evil*. It does *not* return integers or floats. It *executes* code. If you want integers use `int(raw_input(...))`. note that in python3 `raw_input` was renamed `input`.

Comment: It might have been confusion on my part, our teacher uses python 3, I'm still in 2.7.5, since our book is an old python 2 book (and not to mention there is a bit of a language barrier) but now I know, will keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use just one `for`:

```
g = 0 # index for age
n = 0 # index for name
st_names = [0] * 3
st_age = [0] * 3

for n in range(0, 3): # loop used in our book for loading arrays
    st_names[n] = raw_input("Enter Student name")

    st_age[n] = int(raw_input("Enter student age ")) # Change g to n, because that's the variable increment in the loop

print st_names
print st_age
```

Comment: (facepalm) wow, I can't believe I didn't see that, thanks for that, big assignment from school.

Comment: range(3) == range(0, 3)   
input uses eval, I would prefer raw_input

Comment: in py2k `input()` is evil